# Sails generate-oauth

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I following this link [sails-generate-oauth](https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth/blob/master/README.md) to generate oauth with sails, i follow and make all steps as in the refered page say but i am getting this error:

```
root@Ubuntu:~/sailTests/guatour# sails lift
info: Starting app...

 /root/sailTests/guatour/config/routes.js:50
'get /login': 'AuthController.login',
^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected string
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-  all/index.js:129:29
at Array.forEach (native)
at requireAll (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-all/index.js:44:9)
at buildDictionary (/root/sailTests/guatour/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-build-dictionary/index.js:68:14)
at Function.module.exports.aggregate (/root/sailTests/guatour/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-build-dictionary/index.js:190:9)
at Array.loadOtherConfigFiles (/root/sailTests/guatour/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/moduleloader/index.js:164:27)
at /root/sailTests/guatour/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:484:38
at _each (/root/sailTests/guatour/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:13)
at Object.async.auto (/root/sailTests/guatour/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:455:9)
```

Am i missing something?
Thanks for your help, regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, i found my error, it was a coma, before the (/) route (default).